# Adding Link to Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

UPDATE I GOT THE PROBLEM.

in the link I was using ' inspite of " so this all was creating the problem well I have to add something like

```
'<div style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a expr:href='data:post.url'><img src="' + img[0].src + '" width="218px" height="170px"/></a></div>'
```

What to do now to make " ' still not effecting the code

I have a JavaScript

```
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID) {
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = 0;
    if (img.length >= 1) {
        imgtag = '<div style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img src="' + img[0].src + '" width="218px" height="170px"/></div>';
        summ = 0;
    }
    var summary = imgtag;
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```

which produces a image for one of my site. Now I want to add link to the image produced but adding

```
<a href="url"><div style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="218px" height="170px"/></div></a>
```

OR

```
<div style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a href="url"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="218px" height="170px"/></a></div>
```

Does not work. It messes with the code.

Comment: Tried you replace `div` to `a`? You will create link from container.

Comment: That should work, what does the messed up result look like?

Comment: @M1K1O Was checking all options so that nothing is left which I hadn't tried :P

Comment: @Raidri In the messed up result the width and height of the images change back to its normal size

Comment: Maybe some jsFiddle may help to see, what's happening.

Comment: What is ["not working" ???](http://jsfiddle.net/KQpe9/136/) If you are talking about that floated div elements are drawn out of the container, use `overflow:auto;` fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use JQuery's [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap your image in an anchor.

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/pePDN/3/)

```html
<img id="myImage"
  src="http://placehold.it/250x150/00ffcc&text=FooBar"
  title="This is my image" />
```

```js
var createSummaryThumb = function (elementId) {
    var link = $('<a />').attr('href', $(elementId).attr('src'));
    $(elementId).wrap(link);
}

createSummaryThumb('#myImage');
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use a Div more & pure JS

http://jsfiddle.net/pePDN/5/

```
  var a=document.createElement('a');
  a.href='http://www.google.com';
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  b=a.appendChild(image);
  document.getElementById('myImage').appendChild(a);
```